# Illegal argument error while setting foreign key

Tags: java, spring, jpa

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:       The method setTblDepartment(TblDepartment) in the type
>   TblProject is not applicable for the arguments (Long)

### **Code in service layer**

```
public void setFkDeptIdForProject(Long projectId, Long departmentId) {
    TblProject existProj=projectDAO.get(projectId);
    TblDepartment dept= new TblDepartment();
    dept.setPkDepartmentId(departmentId);
    existProj.setTblDepartment(dept);
    projectDAO.update(existProj);
}
```

## **TblProject.class**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id")
public TblDepartment getTblDepartment() {
    return this.tblDepartment;
}

public void setTblDepartment(TblDepartment tblDepartment) {
    this.tblDepartment = tblDepartment;
}
```

Comment: do not run broken program, it has not sense, read careful and correct compilation errors. Maybe not only one

Comment: code is not complete, i.e. hide declaration

Comment: You are somewhere probably passing `Long` as argument to the method `setTblDepartment` which is expecting an object of `TblDepartment`.